# Need to get the negation for set of fields in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the negation of more than one field in one go and following is what I wrote.

```
orig_code send_id ref_no
ABCD001   ABCD001 35RE777
ABCDXXX   ABCDXXX 35RE156
ABCD001   ABCD001 20PS789
ABCDXXX   ABCDXXX 20PS453
ABCD001   ABCD001 30RE745
ABCDXXX   ABCDXXX 55RE741
DBWS001   ABCD001 25PS369
MNKSXXX   ABCDXXX 21PS258
ABCD001   ABCD001 25PS369
ABCDXXX   ABCDXXX 21PS258

SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE
((orig_code, send_id) NOT IN
                         ( ('ABCD001', 'ABCD001'),
                          ('ABCDXXX', 'ABCDXXX'))
AND (ref_no NOT LIKE '35RE%' OR ref_no NOT LIKE '20PS%'))
```

The query I wrote does not remove the content in the above table. Please let me know where I have made the mistake.

The Result I'm looking for is the following. There may be multiple reference formats and I have only included few. I only need to remove the ones with start with 35RE or 20PS while satisfying the orig_code and send_id field values.

```
ABCD001   ABCD001 30RE745
ABCDXXX   ABCDXXX 55RE741
DBWS001   ABCD001 25PS369
MNKSXXX   ABCDXXX 21PS258
ABCD001   ABCD001 25PS369
ABCDXXX   ABCDXXX 21PS258
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: If I run a query with that WHERE condition on that data, I will get no data. What would you expect instead?

Comment: I didn't copy paste all the query  content. Just Only the part of it. I do have the select, from and where clauses :). Anyway I have updated the question.

Comment: That was clear enough. My question is: what is your expected result?

Comment: I have updated the table and the expected result. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/434f9/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( orig_code, send_id, ref_no ) AS
SELECT 'ABCD001', 'ABCD001', '35RE777' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCDXXX', 'ABCDXXX', '35RE156' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCD001', 'ABCD001', '20PS789' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCDXXX', 'ABCDXXX', '25PS453' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCD001', 'ABCD001', '30RE745' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCDXXX', 'ABCDXXX', '55RE741' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCD001', 'ABCD001', '25PS369' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABCDXXX', 'ABCDXXX', '21PS258' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t1
WHERE  (
         (orig_code, send_id) NOT IN (
           ('ABCD001', 'ABCD001'),
           ('ABCDXXX', 'ABCDXXX')
         )
         OR (                             -- OR rather than AND
             ref_no NOT LIKE '35RE%'
         AND ref_no NOT LIKE '20PS%'      -- AND rather than OR
         )
       )
```

**Query 2** or alternatively using `NOT(A) AND NOT(B) = NOT( A OR B )` and `NOT(A) OR NOT(B) = NOT( A AND B )`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t1
WHERE  NOT (
         (orig_code, send_id) IN (
           ('ABCD001', 'ABCD001'),
           ('ABCDXXX', 'ABCDXXX')
         )
         AND (
             ref_no LIKE '35RE%'
         OR ref_no LIKE '20PS%'
         )
       )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/434f9/7/1)**:

```
| ORIG_CODE | SEND_ID |  REF_NO |
|-----------|---------|---------|
|   ABCDXXX | ABCDXXX | 25PS453 |
|   ABCD001 | ABCD001 | 30RE745 |
|   ABCDXXX | ABCDXXX | 55RE741 |
|   ABCD001 | ABCD001 | 25PS369 |
|   ABCDXXX | ABCDXXX | 21PS258 |
```

Comment: Thanks MT0, this solved my issue. I'm working on the total query now. Hope everything will be fine after this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

According to your latest example, this is enough:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE ref_no NOT LIKE '35RE%'
  and ref_no NOT LIKE '20PS%'
```

With your data:

```
with T1(orig_code, send_id, ref_no) as (
    select 'ABCD001', 'ABCD001', '35RE777' from dual union all
    select 'ABCDXXX', 'ABCDXXX', '35RE156' from dual union all
    select 'ABCD001', 'ABCD001', '20PS789' from dual union all
    select 'ABCDXXX', 'ABCDXXX', '20PS453' from dual union all
    select 'ABCD001', 'ABCD001', '30RE745' from dual union all
    select 'ABCDXXX', 'ABCDXXX', '55RE741' from dual union all
    select 'DBWS001', 'ABCD001', '25PS369' from dual union all
    select 'MNKSXXX', 'ABCDXXX', '21PS258' from dual union all
    select 'ABCD001', 'ABCD001', '25PS369' from dual union all
    select 'ABCDXXX', 'ABCDXXX', '21PS258' from dual
)
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE ref_no NOT LIKE '35RE%'
  and ref_no NOT LIKE '20PS%'

ORIG_CODE SEND_ID REF_NO 
--------- ------- -------
ABCD001   ABCD001 30RE745
ABCDXXX   ABCDXXX 55RE741
DBWS001   ABCD001 25PS369
MNKSXXX   ABCDXXX 21PS258
ABCD001   ABCD001 25PS369
ABCDXXX   ABCDXXX 21PS258
```